# Does Gitlab Wiki markdown support a "quote of the day" generator that pulls from CSV file?

Tags: gitlab, markdown, wiki

I'm trying to spruce up our wiki and I've seen a random quote generator in other wikis. Hoping the gitlab markdown supports this. By the way, I have an unreal list of amazing and unique quotes if your interested I'll post them here if I get this to work!

Comment: I am trying to set up the same in my company, I am very interested in that list of quotes if you still have them and are happy to share!

Answer (score 1):

No, [GitLab Markdown](https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/user/markdown.html) doesn't support anything like that. Dynamic content generally isn't supported by any flavour of Markdown.